# KnockoutJs: directly address observableArray object in view

Tags: knockout.js

I want to loop through an observableArray of objects and in this loop, I have to get the corresponding value of another observableArray. I do not succeed in doing this.

My code is as follow.

Model and viewmodel:

```
//**********MODEL********************
function Configuration() {
var self = this;

self.properties = ko.observableArray();
}

function deviceProperty() {
    var self = this;

    self.property = ko.observable("");
    self.value = ko.observable("");
}

//**********VIEWMODEL****************
function compareModelView() {
var self = this;

self.config1 = ko.observable(new Configuration);
self.config2 = ko.observable(new Configuration);

$().ready(function () {
    //Load config1 and config2
});

}

//**********jQuery********************
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new compareModelView());
    });
})(jQuery);
```

View:

```
<!-- ko foreach: config1().properties -->
     <tr>
     <td data-bind="text: property()"></td>
     <td data-bind="text: value()"></td>
     <td data-bind="text: $root.config2().properties()[$index].value()"></td>
     </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Knockoutjs gives an error, saying that this property doesn't exist.

When I do `$root.config2().properties().length` it returns a number (3).
When I do `$root.config2().properties()[0]` it returns [Object][Object].
When I do `$root.config2().properties()[0]` it returns an empty string.

But I can't see how I can directly address the value property inside the object?

Comment: Why do you want todo that? The view should be clean from code

Comment: @Anders Because I have this model and I want to make a compare screen between different configs.

Comment: But its more MVVM to move the code to the viewmdodel. Thats all im saying.

Comment: You are right, I know. But I'm having this objects generated on another page with an Ajax call. It is more MVVM to make a model wit propertyname, value1, value2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$index` is an observable property (see [doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)), so you need to write `$index()` to get its value.

So the following binding should work:

```
<td data-bind="text: $root.config2().properties()[$index()].value()"></td>
```

Although your main problem was the `$index()` but in itself it won't solve your case because the population order of the collections does matter in this scenario so you get errors with your current setup.

So if you populate first the `config1()` KO starts to bind your table but if the `config2()` has not been populated yet you will get the some undefined errors. To fix it you need change the population order to populate the `config2()` first.

You can play with this here: http://jsfiddle.net/xwjKK just change the order `pupulateConfig2` and `pupulateConfig1` call to see the effect.

Comment: `$root.config2().properties()[$index()].value()` gives `Message: TypeError: $root.config2(...).properties(...)[$index(...)] is undefined;`. Howerver `$root.config2().properties()[$index()]` gives `[object Object]`. So correct for the $index(), but still can't address the value property.

Comment: The `$root.config2().properties()[$index()].value()` should work but if you populate first the `config1()` KO starts to populate your table but if the `config2()` has not been populated yet you get the is undefined message. So you need to populate `config2` first. You can play with this here: http://jsfiddle.net/xwjKK/ just change the order `pupulateConfig2` and `pupulateConfig1` call to see the effect.

Comment: If you don't want to/cannot change the population order you can add some index checking with the `with` bindindg: http://jsfiddle.net/xwjKK/1/